# page not found when creating new controller in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I started learning yii2 framework through [tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whuIf33v2Ug).
Created HelloController.php inside backend\controllers.
Below is the code---

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

When I am trying to load the page as : http://studio.freecodetube.test/hello/index
it is giving 404 error.

What is missing?

Comment: I recommend that at least in the beginning, you use the Gii module to generate code. It works great and saves you time and mistakes.
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/es/start-gii

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this domain is tied to the backend part and not to the web interface?
if yes, then add the backend to the config in the route section

```
 'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'pattern'=>'action/controller',
                'route'=>'action/controller',
            ],
        ],
```